# Is it possible to install Python 3.10.x on a debian 9 server?

Tags: debian, python3

I have a Python web app that uses Flask. 
The production server is running Debian 9 and has Python 3.5.3 installed.

We have added some functionality to the app that uses language features and packages dependent on Python 3.10.x.

I cannot find Python 3.10.x package for Debian 9. At the moment upgrading the server to a more current Debian version or distribution is not an option.

I have already tried to compile Python3.10, 3.9 from source, but get `segmentation fault` error while trying to run the app.

I have tried to compile Python from source using the steps mentioned in
https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-debian-9/

```bash
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.x.x/Python-3.x.x.tgz 
tar xzf Python-3.x.x.tgz 
cd Python-3.x.x 
./configure --enable-optimizations 
make altinstall
```

I have attempted to compile versions 3.10.4, 3.9.13, and 3.8.13 but no luck.
Keep getting `segmentation fault` while trying to run the app.

Also is there a list maintained anywhere about Linux OS distribution vs Python version support?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many other sources of problems, but this might help.  I believe it's more typical to include a couple of compiler/linker flags lines (the last 3 below) when building Python.  No idea really... I've been cargo-culting this.  But the following has generally worked for me:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    --enable-optimizations \
    --with-lto \
    --with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm \
    --with-ensurepip \
    'CFLAGS=-g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' \
    LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,relro" \
    CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

... then `make install` (which puts this in /usr/local/bin etc).